# Delphi connect print service via AIDL

Tags: android, delphi, android-intent

I want to use this Android code in Delphi:

```java
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setPackage("com.sunmi.extprinterservice");
intent.setAction("com.sunmi.extprinterservice.PrinterService");
bindService(intent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection()
{
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service)
    {
        ExtPrinterService interface = ExtPrinterService.Stub.asInterface(service);
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name)
    {
    }
};
```

Use interface object to realize one’s own printing task

```
interface.printText(“123456\n”);
```

Unbind the service after the completion of the usage

```
unbindService(serviceConnection);
```

Comment: Hello, this post could benefit from some more details. Its not immediately clear to me what the problem is. For example, is it working, or is it raising an error (please include that if so).

Comment: @JeffMergler I think the OP is asking how to translate this Java code into Delphi Pascal code.

Comment: ok @remy-lebeau

Answer (score 0):

Here is my first stab at this. I have no way to test this. I also don't have a way to access `ExtPrinterService`. That is obviously another matter probably a manifest declaration and library import step. At the very least, you can see that some of the Java code translates to Delphi in a straight-forward way, once you understand how to work with the interfaces.

```
uses
  Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText,
  Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes,
  Androidapi.Helpers,
  Androidapi.JNIBridge,
  Androidapi.JNI.App,
  Androidapi.JNI.Os

procedure TTabbedForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Intent: JIntent;
  ServiceConnection: JServiceConnection;
begin

  Intent := TJIntent.Create;
  Intent.setPackage(StringtoJString('com.sunmi.extprinterservice'));
  Intent.setAction(StringtoJString('com.sunmi.extprinterservice'));

  ServiceConnection := TJServiceConnection.Create;
  ServiceConnection.onServiceConnected := OnServiceConnected;
  ServiceConnection.onServiceDisconnected := OnServiceDisconnected;
  SharedActivityContext.bindService(Intent, ServiceConnection, TJContext.JavaClass.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

end;

procedure TTabbedForm.OnServiceConnected(name: JComponentName; Binder: JIBinder);
begin
  //
end;

procedure TTabbedForm.OnServiceDisconnected(name: JComponentName);
begin
  //
end;
```